# Find cause of ConnectionReset

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I'm consistently getting SocketError.ConnectionReset when I try to send a packet from my server to a client, via SendAsync. The really frustrating thing is the packet is identical to another packet that works fine, except for the class name. I've read that the only way to determine the cause is to monitor network traffic, is there an easier way? I'm not familiar with that process, if that is the only way, if you have any tips to do that, please share them!

Here's the code that I currently use to send the packet:

```
       private bool StartSend()
    {
        Log.Net("[" + ConnectionId + "] StartSend m_iSendBufferLength=" + m_iSendBufferLength + " m_iBytesSent=" + m_iBytesSent);

        Int32 bytesToSend = m_iSendBufferLength - m_iBytesSent;

        if (bytesToSend > PSSocketServer.SOCKET_OP_BUFFER_LENGTH)
        {
            bytesToSend = PSSocketServer.SOCKET_OP_BUFFER_LENGTH;
        }

        try
        {
            m_SendAsyncEventArgs.SetBuffer(m_SendAsyncEventArgs.Offset, bytesToSend);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Log.Error(exc.ToString());
            return false;
        }

        Buffer.BlockCopy(m_SendBuffer, m_iBytesSent,
                         m_SendAsyncEventArgs.Buffer, m_SendAsyncEventArgs.Offset,
                         bytesToSend);

        try
        {
            Log.Net("[" + ConnectionId + "] SendAsync m_iSendBufferLength=" + m_iSendBufferLength + " m_iBytesSent=" + m_iBytesSent);

            //post asynchronous send operation
            bool willRaiseEvent =
                ConnectionSocket.SendAsync(m_SendAsyncEventArgs);

            if (!willRaiseEvent)
            {
                return ProcessSend();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("Caught Exception '" + e.Message + " Starting PSConnection SendAsync");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

When I setup a new connection, I have the `SocketAsyncEventArgs`, for send & receive. Right after the `SendAsync()` is hit, the `ProcessSend` function shown below is called, and the `m_SendAsyncEventArgs.SocketError` is `ConnectionReset`:

```
                public bool ProcessSend()
    {
        m_iBytesSent += m_SendAsyncEventArgs.BytesTransferred;

        Log.Net("[" + ConnectionId + "] ProcessSend BytesTransferred=" + m_SendAsyncEventArgs.BytesTransferred + " m_iBytesSent=" + m_iBytesSent);

        if (m_SendAsyncEventArgs.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
        {
            Log.Error("Socket Error '" + m_SendAsyncEventArgs.SocketError.ToString() + 
                "' in PSConnection ProcessSend.  Connection ID: " + ConnectionId);
            return false;
        }

        if (m_iBytesSent == m_iSendBufferLength) // this packet is finished sending
        {
            m_SendQueueMutex.WaitOne();
            ResetSendVars();
            m_SendQueueMutex.ReleaseMutex();
            CheckStartSend();
        }
        else // still more of this clump to send
        {
            if (ConnectionSocket != null)
            {
                return StartSend();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Also, an interesting bit of info that may help: if I only serialize three Int32's, the packet gets sent fine, no ConnectionReset, if I add another Int32, the error occurs.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the packet send code. I'm mostly looking to find methods to track down the source of the ConnectionReset, as I was assuming it wasn't debuggable I didn't post any code to begin with.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I've updated the post to include more info about the error, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what the issue was. The client was disconnecting because of an exception thrown when receiving the packet sent from our server, I was focusing on the server-side, but the issue was on the client.